# Do quadratic DGCA's have rational homology series?

Tags: homological-algebra, differential-graded-algebras

Suppose $A$ is a differential graded-commutative algebra (in non-negative degree) over a char-0 field, with $|d| = -1$, such that $A$ is finitely generated in degree $\le 1$ with relations in degree $\le 2$. Suppose $A_0$ is finite-dimensional, so that each $A_i$ is as well. We can form the Hilbert series of its homology:

\begin{equation}H(t) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \text{dim}(H_i(A)) t^i\end{equation}

Is it known if $H(t)$ is rational? I've found the paper 'On the Hilbert series of the homology of differential graded algebras' by Gulliksen, which is obviously relevant, but I don't think it answers my question. Also note that I don't assume $A$ is connected.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using "degree" to mean both homological and polynomial degree? If $A$ is finitely generated (as a ring) by elements of homological degree $0$ and $1$ then the series you write down has a maximal $i$ (equal to the dimension of the degree $1$ generators) and so if the series makes sense, it's polynomial. On the other hand, with generators in homological degree $0$, there is no reason for the terms of this series to be finite; take $k[x]$ with $x$ in degree $0$ and no relations or differential.

Comment: @Gabriel Good point -- here I was assuming $A_0$ is fd, which I edited to add. thanks!

Comment: My first point/question still stands; if "degree" means homological degree throughout your question, then $A_n=0$ for $n\gg 0$ so your series is a polynomial.